# Node rotation value is reset when animating

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm working on an AR project and need to position some 3D models in the scene when a specific image is recognized.
I also need the 3d models to rotate indefinitely around their y axis, which I managed to do with the following code.

```
let spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
spin.fromValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: 0))
spin.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: Float(2 * Double.pi)))
spin.duration = 8
spin.repeatCount = .infinity
modelNode.addAnimation(spin, forKey: nil)
```

The issue I'm encountering is when I try to apply this rotation animation to a node that has been rotated beforehand to be set in the correct starting orientation using

```
modelNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(modelNode.transform, SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(-Double.pi/2), 1, 0, 0))
```

In this case it seems that the animation doesn't take into account the current rotation of the node but uses the original one, nullifying my setup.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can I set a starting object rotation before animating another rotation?

Comment: Your fromvalue is different from current transform in x value, right? Fromvalue is from absolute rotation value. Right?

Comment: Yes, but I also tried setting it with the current object rotation values and removing it altogether (relying only on .toValue for the animation) but with no luck.

Comment: I found the reason. SCNNode.rotation has a signature (x,y,z,w) . The first three are three axises. and the last one is the ratation angle.  But in SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(w,x,y,z) The first one is angle. So your animation rotates around the Y axe, while your original one is rotated by X axe. The correct fromValue should be  NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: Float(-Double.pi/2))). Hope this is helpful.